# ¿Es posible enviar un icono de Fontawesome a un componente?

Tags: reactjs

Básicamente lo que estoy intentando hacer es tener un solo componente que me arme varios items. Los items consisten solamente en un titulo, una descripcion, y el ícono. los primeros dos los envio sin problemas, pero ya el segundo no se me ocurre como mandarlo, ya que si lo envio como como los otros dos, no se muestra por pantalla.

ejemplo:

éste son los items que quiero mostrar:

```
<IndexComponent titulo='Asistencia Profesional' texto = 'Contamos con un equipo de pre-venta especializado y un departamento de ingeniería para los proyectos más complejos' icono = 'faPeopleGroup'/>
<IndexComponent titulo='Training y seguimiento' texto = 'Capacitaciones para canales e integradores, acerca de instalación y puesta en marcha de nuestros productos, acompañándolos en el proceso de postventa.' icono = 'faPeopleGroup'/>
<IndexComponent titulo='Crédito y Financiación' texto = 'Ofrecemos financiación estándar y especial tanto para el área de distribución, como también para cualquier tipo de proyecto.' icono = 'faPeopleGroup'/>
<IndexComponent titulo='Centro de distribución' texto = 'Contamos con un depósito en el cual nuestro equipo se encarga de realizar la logística en tiempo y forma acompañando el dinamismo del negocio' icono = 'faPeopleGroup'/>
```

Y asi lo recibo en el componente:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faPeopleGroup } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const IndexComponent = (props) => {
    const titulo = props.titulo;
    const texto = props.texto;
    const icono = props.icono;


    return (
        <>
            <div className='component'>
                <h4>{titulo}</h4>
                <p>{texto}</p>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icono} color="#003a82"/>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

El problema es que aunque importe el icono o `FontAwesome`, no logro mostrarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es posible ésto que planteo? Enviar un icono desde un componente a otro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo siguiendo las indicaciones de la [documentación](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons) de la siguiente manera:

```
import { solid, regular, brands, icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/import.macro'
```

Importas los macros y a continuación:

```
<IndexComponent titulo='...' texto = '...' icono={solid('faPeopleGroup')} />
```

Y ahora si podrías usar el icono:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={icono} color="#003a82"/>
```